# Scala print foo/bar alternately

Tags: scala, concurrency

I'm trying to code this [LeetCode exercise](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/) of printing foo/bar alternately in Scala using conventional Runnables with wait(), notifyAll(), but can't get it to produce the wanted output, which should be:

```
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

Here's the code:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Foo extends Runnable {
  @Override def run(): Unit = { print("foo ") }
}

class Bar extends Runnable {
  @Override def run(): Unit = { print("bar ") }
}

val printFoo = new Foo
val printBar = new Bar

class FooBar {
  private var foosLoop: Boolean = false

  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  def foo: Unit = for (_ <- 1 to 5) synchronized {
      while (foosLoop) { wait() }
      printFoo.run()
      foosLoop = true
      notifyAll()
    }

  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  def bar: Unit = for (_ <- 1 to 5) synchronized {
      while (!foosLoop) { wait() }
      printBar.run()
      foosLoop = false
      notifyAll()
    }
}

val fb = new FooBar
fb.foo
fb.bar

// Output:
// foo    <=== prints only first "foo "
```

Could someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

My second question is: Can it be implemented with Scala Futures replacing Runnables?

**UPDATE**:

The posted code actually works as long as `fb.foo` and `fb.bar` are to be called from separate threads.

```
val tFoo = new Thread (new Runnable { @Override def run(): Unit = fb.foo })
val tBar = new Thread (new Runnable { @Override def run(): Unit = fb.bar })

tFoo.start()
tBar.start()
```

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

No idea, I haven't used **Runnables** in my life, and they are not used in **Scala**.
*(and I would say that are also not used anymore in **Java** too)*

> Can it be implemented with Scala Futures replacing Runnables?

Yes, something like this:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object RunAlternately {
  /**
   * Runs two taks concurrently and alternating between the two.
   * @param n the amout of times to run each task.
   * @param aTaks the first task.
   * @param bTaks the second task.
   */
  def apply(n: Int)(aTask: => Unit)(bTask: => Unit)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] ={
    val aLock = new Semaphore(1)
    val bLock = new Semaphore(0)
    
    def runOne(task: => Unit, thisLock: Semaphore, thatLock: Semaphore): Future[Unit] =
      Future {
        var i = 0
        while (i < n) {
          thisLock.acquire()
          task
          thatLock.release()
          i += 1
        }
      }
    
    val aFuture = runOne(aTask, thisLock = aLock, thatLock = bLock)
    val bFuture = runOne(bTask, thisLock = bLock, thatLock = aLock)
    
    aFuture.flatMap(_ => bFuture)
  }
}
```

*See it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/jIRtGOjPSTCee5gDRLHclQ/5).*

---

However, these kind of things are usually better modelled with even higher-level APIs like **IO** or **Streams**.